# onQueryTextChange + FirebaseAdapter

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, firebase-realtime-database, searchview

I am looking for a way of filtering my data in a RecyclerView using a searchView but am still stuck. I read this post [Filtering a recyclerview with a firebaserecycleradapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34382923/filtering-a-recyclerview-with-a-firebaserecycleradapter) and [Filter data on firebase using Searchview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39085182/filter-data-on-firebase-with-searchview), but there is no any clear answer. And they are the only posts available.

There are also no clear examples on this issue. I am looking for a full simple example on Filtering data in a `RecyclerView` with `Firebase` using `SearchView`.

Below is `Load()`  method ic all it in `OnCreate()` to load the list of Items.

```
 void Load(){
        //   mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthLitsener);

        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Event,EventViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter_ = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Event, GraduationListActivity.EventViewHolder>(Event.class,
                R.layout.item_event_view,
                GraduationListActivity.EventViewHolder.class,
                queryRef) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(GraduationListActivity.EventViewHolder viewHolder, final Event model, final int position) {
                final String key_post = getRef(position).getKey();
                viewHolder.setEventLocation(model.getEventLocation());
                viewHolder.setEventName(model.getEventName());
                viewHolder.setEventType(model.getEventType());
                viewHolder.setEventDate(model.getEventDate());
                viewHolder.setEventPic(c, model.getEventImage());
                viewHolder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // Toast.makeText(EventViewActivity.this,"This is : "+position,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        Intent loadMainActivity = new Intent(GraduationListActivity.this,BlogActivity.class);
                        loadMainActivity.putExtra("PARTY_NAME", model.getEventName());
                        startActivity(loadMainActivity);
                    }
                });
            }
        };

        mRecyclerview_event_view.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter_);
    }
```

and this is my `onCreateOptionsMenu()`

```
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.search, menu);

        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menu.findItem(R.id.action_search));

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
                // ????????
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                //??????
                return true;
            }
        });

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

So am using a searchView to search but am confused: what should I put in `onQueryTextChange()` and `onQueryTextSubmit()` according to Firebase?

Comment: You can use onQueryTextChange to get text from searchView.